# How do I encode a UUID to make it JSON serializable

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using UUID instead of the default Django incremental IDs. However, now I get the following error:

```
file "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py",
line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") TypeError: UUID('4fd5a26b452b4f62991d76488c71a554') is not JSON serializable
```

Here is my serializer file:

```
class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ("id", "created_at", "merchant_uri", "api_key",
                  "status", 'owner_email', 'business_type', 'full_name',
                  'owner_phone_number', 'marketplace_name', 'domain_url',
                  'support_email', 'support_phone_number', 'postal_code',
                  'street_address', 'current_processor',
                  'current_monthly_volume')
```

Answer (score 3):

This usually means you need to force your UUID to be serialized as a string, which can be done with the `CharField`. Some UUID field implementations for Django [will do this by default](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), but it appears as though the one you are using will return the raw `UUID` object. By setting the field to a `CharField`, this will force it to be converted to a string.

```
class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ("id", "created_at", "merchant_uri", "api_key",
                  "status", 'owner_email', 'business_type', 'full_name',
                  'owner_phone_number', 'marketplace_name', 'domain_url',
                  'support_email', 'support_phone_number', 'postal_code',
                  'street_address', 'current_processor',
                  'current_monthly_volume')
```

This will convert it to a string manually and will give you the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-uuidfield](https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield), it serializes automatically.